# Реализация рекуррентной сети на Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

Доброго времени суток.
Начал изучать Keras и столкнулся с проблемой. У них довольно скудная документация, а примеров не достаточно чтобы понять функционал.
Если существуют ресурсы с русской документацией буду рад ссылкам.

Давайте рассмотрим пример.

Есть вектор 
(размерности скажем 10000000)
целочисленных значений (от 0 до 64)
в котором содержатся разность соседних значений функции в формате: 
(значение[i]-значение[i+1])*10000+32

Необходимо используя 100 значений данного вектора получить 101-е значение и т.д.

Для начала я планирую исползовать слой Embedding с размером словаря 64 который
будет отдавать 100 слоев длинной в 64 значения.
 (я так понимаю он будет строить из каждого числа вектор со значением 0 по всем индексам, кроме индекса равного входному числу, где будет значение будет 1)

Далее планирую использовать 3 связанных lstm слоя:

1й lstm должен принимать на вход 100 слоев,

2й lstm должен принимать на вход 80 слоев сначиная с 20-го слоя предыдущего lstm,

3й lstm должен принимать на вход 60 слоев сначиная с 20-го слоя предыдущего lstm,

Далее выходной вектор (размерностью 64 я так понимаю) проганяю через softmax с выходом 64

Ошибка вычисляется:
1-выходной_вектор[101-значение_входного вектора]

но как это все записать я так и не понял.

Буду очень благодарен если ктото напишет этих 10 строчек и поможет мне понять как это все работает.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Можете разбить текст на логические блоки? Сложно разобратся в сплошном массиве строк.

Comment: Отредактировал разбив на блоки.